# How to fix an app that is modifying or disabling SELinux on the device to resubmit to Google Play

Tags: android, selinux

yesterday I wanted to submit my app and after like a minute I got the following message from Google:

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> I reviewed your app, com.***.***, and had to
>   reject it because it violates the malicious behavior policy. If you
>   submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on
>   Google Play.
>
> Here’s how you can submit your app for another review:
>
> Make the appropriate changes to your app. We determined that your app
>   degrades a user’s device security by modifying or disabling SELinux on
>   the device. Apps that introduce or exploit security vulnerabilities
>   are explicitly prohibited. Read through the Malicious Behavior policy
>   for more details. Make sure your app is compliant with all other
>   policies listed in the Developer Program Policies. Remember that
>   additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy issues
>   with your apps. Sign in to your Developer Console and submit the
>   modified, policy compliant APK. Make sure to increment the version
>   number of the APK. If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this
>   rejection may have been in error, please reach out to our policy
>   support team. One of my colleagues will get back to you within 2
>   business days.
>
> Best,
>
> Lena
>
> Google Play Review Team

So I actually do not know where I offend that policy. I searched for the keywords in my code:

setenforce
getenforce

But it's not there

And I also checked my permissions in the Android Manifest, nothing to worry about I guess:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

So I am wondering how to fix my app, that I can resubmit it and it will appear in Google Play!

Thank You for your help!

Best,
Manuel

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had these SDK included in project:

- AppLovin
- Facebook
- LeadBolt
- MoPub
- RevMob
- Upsight
- Vungle

I have deleted all of them except Vungle. After that I received another message from Google. This time they warned me about Vungle version. I had to update Vungle SDK to version 3.3 or higher.

Now my app is published without any problems.

So If you have any of the above SDKs, try removing one by one and upload new version of APK. (I removed all, since I didn't need them)